# How zsh does store history? History file format

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I am not sure if I fully understand how zsh stores its history. Example line:

`: 1458291931:0;ls -l`

I guess we have here:

- timestamp: **1458291931**
- command: **ls -l**

but what this mystical **0** in between means?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is the so-called *extended history format, which is enabled by the [`EXTENDED_HISTORY` shell option](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#History). The second number (the "mystical **0**") is the duration of the command. "0" either means that the command finished quickly or - depending on your settings - that the duration is not saved. If either of the [shell options](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#History) `INC_APPEND_HISTORY` or `SHARE_HISTORY` is enabled (you can check this with `setopt | grep -E '^(incappend|share)history$'`), then `zsh` will write the history entry to the history file immediately after confirming the command. The duration will be saved as "0" in that case.

If you want to make use of the duration metric while still saving the history to file during shell sessions, you can set the option `INC_APPEND_HISTORY_TIME`, in which case `zsh` will wait for command completion before writing the entry. Obviously this will otherwise behave like `INC_APPEND_HISTORY`.

**Note**: only one of the options `INC_APPEND_HISTORY`, `INC_APPEND_HISTORY_TIME` and `SHARE_HISTORY` should be active